# How to set initial value to select formly field in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I 've created a custom select type component using an api to fill the dropdown list.
There is a stackblitz example for this.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-fed-select-dj8xrg?file=app/app.component.ts)
I can't set an initial value for the select type component.In fact, I m using this code with groups where there is no constructor to call a service so I can't solve it. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fforms%2Fgroups%2Faddress.group.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [compareWith](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#properties).

> Tracks the option comparison algorithm for tracking identities when
>   checking for changes.

**component.html**

```
<mat-select
    [compareWith]="compareFn" 
      [id]="id"
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [formlyAttributes]="field"
      [multiple]="to.multiple"
      (selectionChange)="to.change && to.change(field, formControl)"
      [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
    >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of to.options">
        <mat-option [value]="item" [disabled]="item.disabled">{{
          item.name
        }}</mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
```

**component.ts**

```
compareFn(o1: any, o2: any) {
    return o1.id === o2.id;
}
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-fed-select-jr7oex)

Comment: How can i get the value of the selected field?

Comment: if you are using reactive form then you can get selected value something like this this.form.get('controlName').value